# Test Bitset using GTest

Tags: c++, googletest, bitset

How can I test whether every element in a bitset has same value using gmock and gtest. I am looking for something like below which does not compile

```
bitset<25> flags;
ASSERT_THAT(flags, AllOf(Eq(true)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"How can I test whether every element in a bitset has same value using gmock and gtest."*

The `AllOf()` matcher is meant to combine other matchers as explained in the [reference documentation](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_6_CheatSheet#Composite_Matchers).
The single `Eq(true)` requires to have `flags` an automatic cast operator for `bool` (or at least `int`), which actually isn't available with [`std::bitset<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). That's why your approach doesn't compile.

You can easily do something like

```
bitset<25> flags;
// ...
ASSERT_TRUE(flags.all());
```

That function is available from [`std::bitset<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/all_any_none).

---

Some more alternatives:

```
ASSERT_TRUE(flags.any());
```

---

```
ASSERT_TRUE(flags.none());
```

---

```
bitset<25> expected_value("1100111001110011100111001");

ASSERT_EQUAL(expected_value,flags);
```